# Check if value inside the list in dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Lets say I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {'A': ['one', 'two'], 'B': [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'C': [11, 12]}
```

I want to check if some value is in the dictionary. This is what I try and what I get:

```
>>>value = 'one'
>>>value in dict.values()
False
```

I assume this is because my value is in list. How do I check simply if the value is in any list of values then?

Comment: You shouldn't *assume*: test your hypothesis.  `print(dict.values())` will show your search list.  Continue from there.  Also, simply searching for the problem brings up multiple solutions on this site.  We expect you to do this research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a "simple" way. You should iterate over each list and perform a check:

```
any(value in val for val in dict.values())
```

Comment: Is there a way to find a key of that value? For example, in that case get 'A'?

Comment: `next(key for key, val in dict.items() if value in val)`